# onChange event on apex:inputField fires only after losing focus

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction, inputfield

I have written a VF page having `<apex:inputField>` with a `onchange` method like this:

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!opp[field]}" onchange="resetValues()"/>
```

The method `resetValues` is a `actionFunction`, which clears a `pageBlockSection`, and it works fine.

Below is the actionFunction code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="resetValues" action="{!resetPrices}"
     rerender="priceSection,messages" status="loadingStatus" immediate="true"/>
```

`resetPrices` is written in controller, which sets few fields in `priceSection` to `null`

The `commandbutton` code which is used is this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Get Prices" rerender="priceSection,messages" 
action="{!getPrices}" status="loadingStatus"/>
```

Now, when I enter a value in the `inputField`, the change event won't
fire until I do a Tab Out. So when a user enters a value and doesn't
tab out and directly clicks a button(Get Prices)(which triggers some other
action), the button click event is not fired, only the change event
gets fired.

I cannot use `keyUp` or `keyDown` attributes as I don't want the section to be reset before user has completed typing.

**I want the button click event also be fired once the onchange method is executed.**

Any suggestions, how to handle this?

Comment: Why can't you call the getPrices() method from the resetPrices() method?

Comment: So as per the functionality there are multiple fields on change of which I need to reset the currently derived prices. Once user fills in all the fields, he will click the Get Prices button. These two are separate processes, which I cannot combine